# touchslider.com how to add a few options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

using the code from http://touchslider.com

1.) how can the "currentClass" (the image it starts with) be set to random?
so any one of the images will appear on load?

<s>2.) how can you toggle the script by clicking on an image?</s>

to be more specific, there are navigation links and the images that you can click/swipe
how can you set it up so that when you click on an image, it locks to that image, disabling the navigation links and swipe??

edit: 2nd option solved +

I was able to work around editing the touchslider.com script, and made the 2nd option requested possible by using a transparent div.

JS (in body)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var $content = $("#disablediv1").hide();
$(".lock").on("click", function(e){
$content.toggle();
});
});
</script>
```

HTML (wrap image)

```
<a class="lock" href="#"><img src="IMAGELINK"></img></a>
```

HTML (transparent div positioned over links to be disabled)

```
<div id="disablediv1"></div>
```

CSS (for transparent div)

```
#disablediv1{
position:absolute;
left:200px;
top:20px;
width:600px;
height:544px;
z-index:999;
}
```

^hopefully someone will find that helpful.

*I'm still looking for a way to have the slider show it's first image at random...

Answer (score 0):

*I tidied up the original HTML and CSS in the touchslider example.*
http://touchslider.com/

**Working example.**

http://jsfiddle.net/jvt7U/1/

This works like an image preloader, for efficiency. Image src is excluded from the HTML and there is an array present for images, named gallery.

There are two loops. The first loop sets the random order in the array structure. For example:

```
2,0,1
1,2,0
0,1,2
```

The second loop assigns the image location, based on the image path from the gallery array.

**Random Generator.**

You can search around for better random number generators, and just replace the code here.

```
// Randomize the Array
galleryPosition.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()});
```